# How to detect the user click a hyper-link

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app will display some text, and I want to make the hyper-link be able to be clicked. I have some questions about this feature.

1. How do I parse the text to be aware this is a link?
2. Once a user click the link, I don't want the OS to switch to Safari and open the link, this is very bad because the user can not go back to my application. So I want to open the link within my application. As soon as the user click the link, my app will present a view modally to display the web content. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. You probably want to subclass UILabel.  When you change the text, have it try to see if the text is a hyperlink, if it is, set it to enable user interaction and change the text color to blue.  When the user taps on the link, send a message to the main view controller (Possibly through delegation) to open the link.
2. to display web content in your app, look into UIWebView.

Comment: UIWebView will do both things. You can also look at the dataDetectorTypes of UITextView which will find hyperlinks for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your text can be formatted as html with hyperlinks (`<a>` tags), you could use a UIWebView to display it.

The UIWebViewDelegate's `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method is called when a user taps a link. Usually you would make your controller implement this method, and set the UIWebView's delegate to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to check out a Github project called [LRLinkableLabel](https://github.com/lukeredpath/LRLinkableLabel).

It will auto-detect any URLs that are inside the `.text` property.

You can use it like so:

```
LRLinkableLabel *label = [[LRLinkableLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 20.0)];
label.delegate = self;
label.text = @"Check out http://dundermifflin.com to find some great paper deals!";
```

Then just make sure `self` implements this method:

```
- (void) linkableLabel:(LRLinkableLabel *)label clickedButton:(UIButton *)button forURL:(NSURL *)url {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

You can also use the `linkColor` and `textColor` properties to configure the appearance of the label. From this point you can use it just like any other UILabel.

Remember to set the `delegate` to `nil` when you're all done to make sure everything is all cleaned up.

Hope this helps.